# log4j2.xml producing html and xml log file without format

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm working on web project using jsf and jpa I also use log4j to log mu webapp
the problem is the html lof file look the same as sample log file there is no html layout the same thing with my xml layout
everything fine logging and creating files but there is no layout
the three appenders produce the same log formatt 
here is my log4j2.xml

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="all">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">webapp_logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile  name="DailyRollingLog" fileName="${baseDir}/mylog.log" 
                      filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/prime_hms-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log">
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%"/>
        </RollingFile >
        <RollingFile  name="DailyRollingHTML" fileName="${baseDir}/mylog.html" 
                           filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/prime_hms-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.html">
            <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout">
                <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
            </layout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile  name="DailyRollingXML" fileName="${baseDir}/mylog.xml" 
                           filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/prime_hms-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.xml">
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.XMLLayout">
                 <param name="properties" value="true"/>
                <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
                <param name="complete" value="true"/>
            </layout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="DailyRollingLog"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="DailyRollingHTML"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="DailyRollingXML"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Log4j 2 you never specify a class attribute with a Class name. Log4j 2 uses plugins.  You should have:

```
<HTMLLayout locationInfo="true"/>
```

and

```
<XMLLayout locationInfo="true" complete="true" properties="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you , the html log is worked fine but the xml still the same ( no tags )
I have tried many ways but still not working for the xml log

Comment: Can you update the configuration in your question to show what you have now?

Comment: @rogers Yeah sure, This is my log4j2.xml
because it's too long here is the file on pastebin
[link](http://pastebin.com/B2XBzztR)